# Android app can't connect to hostname but can connect to IP on server

Tags: android, android-emulator, hostname, windows-server

I am having an odd problem with my android app. I can connect and send data when I hardcode my server's IP address, but I get the errors below when I try to use the hostname. I have been testing this through android's emulator on Windows server 2003. I also have made sure to ensure that the address starts with http and that the app uses the internet's permission. Any ideas as to why this could be? E.G I can connect when I use 123.45.678/test.php but not servername/test.php

```
06-12 17:02:30.360: I/Choreographer(642): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 17:03:07.670: I/Choreographer(642): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 17:03:07.810: I/Choreographer(642): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 17:03:16.200: W/System.err(642): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "HOSTNAME": No address associated with hostname
```

Post

```
public void postData(String Filename) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                if (!MainActivity.address.startsWith("https://") && !MainActivity.address.startsWith("http://")){
                    MainActivity.address = "http://" + MainActivity.address;
                }
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(MainActivity.address);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    // Add your data
                    //MainActivity.QRdata.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", "<data><serial><serial>SN001</serial></serial><items><item>Test1 = Failed</item><item>Test2 = Passed</item><item>Test3 = Passed</item></items></data>"));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file", Filename));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Log.v("Response = ", res);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
                //return response.toString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: is your server running?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Yeah, I have enabled PHP on it and can connect either way through a browser.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to that host via any other device, ie PC? And is your host really called HOSTNAME?!

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 Yeah, I can connect with multiple PCs. And haha no, HOSTNAME is just a place holder.

Comment: Would it be possible to look at how you are connecting to your host in your Android app?

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 Definitely, see updated code.

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 If it helps, I have logcat responses from the HTTPPost. There is no response from the hostname but the response from the IP is empty.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that MainActivity.address is a valid URI? I'd use a URI object rather than a string, it might be some url encoding issue.

Comment: Hm I will definitely try that, I allow the user to specify the hostname they would like to connect to so I figured a string would be easier but I will try using a URL object.

Comment: I forgot to mention the silliest of tests: can you connect using the hostname from the device web browser?

Comment: @nyarlathotep77 So after testing for a bit I have found that I cannot connect to the server from the device web browser either. Could this be an underlying issue that I need to address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was special permissions with my company that I did not understand. I was unable to use my app to connect due to security considerations. However, if anyone else runs into the same problem that I did (I just wanted to host a PHP script to use POST), use Google App Engine. I have been using it now and it is everything I have been looking for.
https://appengine.google.com/